# Yii2 Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

В последнее время в yii2 ловлю вот такую ошибку: `Error Call to undefined method stdClass::save()`

Она вылазиет из-за того, что в контроллере пишу такую жесть:

```
public function actionIndex($short = '') {
    if ($short != '') {
        $link = Link::find()->where(['short_url' => $short])->one();
        $link->view += 1;
        $link->save();

        $this->redirect($link->url);
    } else {
        return $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

Строка с ошибкой это `$link->save();`, вообщем как поправить эту вещь, что бы она сохраняла?? Помню в версии 2.0.30 это еще работало сейчас 2.0.42.1 и не робит.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionIndex($short = '') {
    if ($short != '') {
        $link = Link::find()->where(['short_url' => $short])->one();
        $link->updateCounters(['view' => 1]);

        $this->redirect($link->url);
    } else {
        return $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#updateCounters()-detail

Единственный момент, если не ошибаюсь - счётчики не валидируются. Но в вашем случае там число `1`, поэтому всё нормально.